# How to debug a perl script used inside another perlscript?

Tags: perl, debugging

How to debug a perl script used inside another perlscript. We can debug both separately. Is it possible to debug in one step?

Ex:

```
!/user/bin/perl

my $param= 8;

my @res=\`perl extract.pl $config`;

print "The results is ....  @res\n";
```

Similarly, can we debug the perl scripts used inside shell script?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that debugging two programs at once would only complicate things. Why is it not sufficient to get the called program working correctly in isolation?

Comment: @Borodin, I'm not sure I understand this complaint.  While testing components separately is certainly a good practice, testing the integrated system is also necessary.  When doing so, it is useful to be able to debug more than one component at a time.

Comment: Testing a system is different from debugging it. A system isn't debugged in its entirety - the point of modularity is that small pieces of code can be worked on in isolation with the assumption that all dependencies are debugged and functional, or at least not the responsibility of the programmer. However if the called code is not independent but really part of the main program then it has been designed wrongly

Comment: Yes, but in the real world bugs often first appear during integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dynamic solution:

```
my $dswitch = $INC{"perl5db.pl"} ? "-d" : "";
my @res=`perl $dswitch extract.pl $config`;
```

`$INC{"perl5db.pl"}` is true when you are using the debugger, and false when you are not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the dynamic solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can add `-d` switch to the shebang line of the script you are invoking:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -d
```

Answer (score 3):

The "correct" thing to do would be to change your design so you are not calling the other script through a system command.  Then you would have a single debugging environment.

The best design would be to make extract.pl into a module.

You could also use the `do` command to import the code from the other file: `do 'extract.pl'`.  Then the only change needed would probably be the way you pass `$config` in.

Either of these approaches would be quite simple to implement and would have other benefits for continued development.  Maybe you have a good reason not to do it this way, but I would consider this first if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Just debug `extract.pl` passing in the value in `$config`. If you don't know what it is, the age-old printf will do that for you.

```
say "\$config='$config'";
```

And then do:

```
perl -d extract.pl 'Stuff that printed in config'.
```

As the two are isolated processes, the only communication is what is passed on the command line and what is printed by the called script. So the called script *should* be capable of being tested without the calling script. (Unless you've set up some sort of IPC or shared memory or something tricky like that.)